# Getting exception while fetching multiple records from stored procedure using JDBC

Tags: java, sql, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc

I am using below code to fetch multiple records from DB using stored procedure into JAVA.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("xxxx", "xxxx", "xxxx");
    String query="{call stud_proc(?,?)}";
    CallableStatement cstmt=con.prepareCall(query);
    cstmt.setString(1,"e001");
    cstmt.registerOutParameter(2,OracleTypes.CURSOR);
    cstmt.execute();

    ResultSet rs=(ResultSet)cstmt.getObject(2);
    while(rs.next()){
        System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
    }


}
```

The Stored procedure is like below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE stud_proc
(
EID_VAR IN VARCHAR2,
CUR_VAR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
AS
BEGIN
OPEN CUR_VAR FOR
SELECT ENAME FROM EMP WHERE EID=EID_VAR;
END;
```

I am getting below exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Bigger type length than Maximum
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:125)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:162)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.check_error(DatabaseError.java:885)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.buffer2Value(T4CMAREngine.java:2231)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB2(T4CMAREngine.java:1048)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIdcb.receiveCommon(T4CTTIdcb.java:112)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIdcb.receiveFromRefCursor(T4CTTIdcb.java:104)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CResultSetAccessor.unmarshalOneRow(T4CResultSetAccessor.java:165)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIrxd.unmarshal(T4CTTIrxd.java:788)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIrxd.unmarshal(T4CTTIrxd.java:705)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:527)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:180)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.execute_for_rows(T4CCallableStatement.java:783)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1028)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:2888)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:2979)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.execute(OracleCallableStatement.java:4103)
at prac1.Main.main(Main.java:30)
```

I tried as per [How to access this stored Procedure from JDBC Callablestatement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804699/how-to-access-this-stored-procedure-from-jdbc-callablestatement) this link:

```
    String query="{call stud_proc(?,?)}";
    CallableStatement cstmt=con.prepareCall(query);
    cstmt.setString(1,"e001");
    cstmt.registerOutParameter(2,OracleTypes.CURSOR);
    cstmt.execute();


    ResultSet rs=((OracleCallableStatement)cstmt).getCursor(2);
    while(rs.next()){
        System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
}
```

BUT i am still getting same error.Is this database related issue of Oracle Version??

Comment: What version of Oracle db, and what version of jdbc driver are you using?

Comment: @OldProgrammer: Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.3.0 , Oracle JDBC driver Driver Version: 10.1.0.2.0

Comment: What is the name of the oracle jar file you are referencing.

Comment: @OldProgrammer: ojdbc14.jar